# How to get the total number of counts for last not null date in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am very new to google sheet and I am trying to find the number of counts for last non-empty date.

For example:
In the example below, we have the last date "March-4" and there are 5 rows corresponding to that date. So the answer should be 5.

**PUBLIC SHEET**
I have shared the public google sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=517697699

## Example sheet

[image]

## Required Answer

- Here, the last date is March 4 and it has 5 rows so the answer is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the maximum value in the column by using `MAX()`. After finding this value, use `COUNTIF()` to count those values.

`=countif(C:C,MAX(C:C))`

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the value in the last non empty cell in Column C by using this formula anywhere in the sheet `=INDEX(FILTER(C:C, NOT(ISBLANK(C:C))), ROWS( FILTER(C:C, NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)))))`
2. Use `COUNTIF` to find the number of occurrences of the date found in step 1 above.

So the final formula is `=COUNTIF(C:C, INDEX(FILTER(C:C, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))), ROWS(FILTER(C:C, NOT(ISBLANK(C:C))))))`