# How to get the total number of counts for last not null date in google sheets based on another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is a follow up question to:

- [How to get the total number of counts for last not null date in google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906056/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-counts-for-last-not-null-date-in-google-sheets#67906056)

## Question

- How to get the most recent number of companies that I have applied?
- For example, in the google sheet below, I have applied to 5 companies in last date of march4, so the answer is 5.
- NOTE: there are 8 values for march4 but only 5 companies are not-empty.

## Public sheet

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=517697699

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=query({B2:C},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc limit "&countifs(C:C,max(C:C),B:B,"<>")&" ",0)`

To get the number of companies on the most recent applied date:

`=countifs(C:C,max(C:C),B:B,"<>")`

It counts how many times the `max()` date occurs in Col C, where Col B has a value.

`"<>"` is used to denote 'not empty'.

[image]

Comment: I need number 5 (not the names of companies)

Comment: OK, that's `=countifs(C:C,max(C:C),B:B,"<>")`.